# Why every? function returns true with empty vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

I came across this weird behaviour:

```
(every? true? [])
=> true

(every? false? [])
=> true

(every? odd? [])
=> true
```

And list goes like that...

It should return **false** instead of *true* I guess.

What is the reason of this function designed that way?

Comment: Could you please specify which of the numbers in `[]` that are not `odd?`, not `false?`, and not `true?` which is what is needed for `every?` to return `false` as the result?

Comment: What does "non-arg parameter" mean? Could that be change to "empty" without changing the meaning of your question?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt you were right! changed the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general rule in most languages that have functions like `every?` and `not-any?` is that they return the identity value when given an empty array. This ensures that you get the same result when you combine operations on subsets of the array. The rule is that

```
(and (every? true? array1) (every? true? array2))
```

should return the same thing as

```
(every? true? (concat array1 array2))
```

If `every?` returned `false` for an empty array, this would break the equivalence when either of the two arrays is empty.

Similarly, `not-any?` returns `false` for an empty array to ensure that

```
(not-any? true? (concat array1 array2))
```

is the same as

```
(or (not-any? true? array1) (not-any? true? array2))
```